# Azure VM Scale Set: When exactly is a state change considered 'complete'?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I'm asking because this is relevant for the autorepair grace period.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-automatic-instance-repairs#grace-period

> When an instance goes through a state change operation because of a PUT, PATCH or POST action performed on the scale set (for example reimage, redeploy, update, etc.), then any repair action on that instance is performed only after waiting for the grace period. Grace period is the amount of time to allow the instance to return to healthy state. The grace period starts after the state change has completed.

We use a stock image, and then use the custom scripts extension to configure the machine. These scripts take a long time, think ~30 minutes.
I've seen that when the custom scripts throw an error, that the VM creation is then marked as a failure.

What's not clear to me, is whether the run time of these custom scripts is included in the 'state change' or not.

Has anyone tested this, is there documentation of this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The state of the scale set is entirely dependent on the [health probe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-health-extension) configured. If your application/service needs to wait for the a script to run so that it becomes available, then that's when the state will change to healthy.

So, the VMSS is considered completely deployed when the application is reachable.